# Connect on-prem jypyter notebook to mlflow tracking server in Azure

Tags: azure-databricks, mlflow

Is it possible to connect a notebook running in premises to an mlflow Tracking server that is part of an Azure Databricks workspace? Have all the local logging and tracking saved in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, used python and solved it with the following steps:

1. Install mlflow and datbricks-cli libraries.
2. Define the following env variables : DATABRICKS_HOST (databricks workspace url: https://region.azuredatabricks.net) and DATABRICKS_TOKEN
3. Define mlflow client:

```py
mlflow_client = mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient(tracking_uri='databricks')
```

5. Use mlflow_client client for logging, saving and etc..

for more reference you can look at the "Log to a tracking server from a notebook" section [here](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/applications/mlflow/tracking.html#log-to-a-tracking-server-from-a-notebook)

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps in the accepted answer, I couldn't use the mlflow_client object. 
What worked is setting the tracking uri directly on mlflow:

```
mlflow.set_tracking_uri('databricks')
```